# how to handle routes that don't match a pattern

Tags: react-router

Is there a way to specify a route handler that handles all routes that do not match the routes defined?  Like a catch-all route or a default route handler.

I'm running into the use case where I want a default page to load if no matching routes are found. For example, it would load a "page not found" page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `v4` of `react-router` you can just add a `Route` without a `path` prop component as the last one in your route definition and it will be matched if no other routes are matched:

Example [copied](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match) from the `react-router` docs:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
  <Redirect from="/old-match" to="/will-match"/>
  <Route path="/will-match" component={WillMatch}/>
  <Route component={NoMatch}/>
</Switch>
```

Here is the url path is not `/`, `/old-match` or `/will-match` the `NoMatch` component is shown.

In `v3` of `react-router` the same principle applies: You just add an `Route` component with just the wildcard character `*` in the `path` prop to the end of your routing definition:

```
<Router ... >
  { /* Your actual route declarations */ }
  <Route component={ NoMatch } path="*" />
</Router>
```

Hope this helps!